# ROS PCL visualizer fails on Turtlebot

Tags: kinect, pcl, turtlebot, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to run PCL visualizer on the turtlebot's computer such that it will subscribe to the Kinect and display a point cloud, and request three floor points from the mouse. It will use this to create and visualize a point cloud that detects people. This is from a PCL tutorial. The code I have used to run this is below. When I run the code on a separate computer that is directly connected to a Kinect, the visualizer runs fine. However, when I run it on the turtlebot, the initial point cloud is displayed, but after I input the three points and run the second point cloud, it exits and displays the following error:

```
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
```

Any thoughts? Here is the code.

Thank you!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <pcl/console/parse.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include <pcl/visualization/pcl_visualizer.h>    
#include <pcl/io/openni_grabber.h>
#include <pcl/sample_consensus/sac_model_plane.h>
#include <pcl/people/ground_based_people_detection_app.h>
#include <pcl/common/time.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/PointCloud2.h>
#include <pcl_conversions/pcl_conversions.h>

typedef pcl::PointXYZRGBA PointT;
typedef pcl::PointCloud<PointT> PointCloudT;

// PCL viewer //
pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer viewer("PCL Viewer");
    
// Mutex: //
boost::mutex cloud_mutex;
bool new_cloud_available_flag;
enum { COLS = 640, ROWS = 480 };

int print_help()
{
  cout << "*******************************************************" << std::endl;
  cout << "Ground based people detection app options:" << std::endl;
  cout << "   --help    <show_this_help>" << std::endl;
  cout << "   --svm     <path_to_svm_file>" << std::endl;
  cout << "   --conf    <minimum_HOG_confidence (default = -1.5)>" << std::endl;
  cout << "   --min_h   <minimum_person_height (default = 1.3)>" << std::endl;
  cout << "   --max_h   <maximum_person_height (default = 2.3)>" << std::endl;
  cout << "   --sample  <sampling_factor (default = 1)>" << std::endl;
  cout << "*******************************************************" <<std::endl;
}

 PointCloudT::Ptr cloud(new PointCloudT);

void callback(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr& msg){
   cloud_mutex.lock();
   sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 msg0 = *msg;
   PointCloudT cloud0;
   pcl::fromROSMsg(msg0, cloud0);
   *cloud = cloud0;
   new_cloud_available_flag = true;
   cloud_mutex.unlock();
 }

struct callback_args{
  // structure used to pass arguments to the callback function
  PointCloudT::Ptr clicked_points_3d;
  pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer::Ptr viewerPtr;
};

void
pp_callback (const pcl::visualization::PointPickingEvent& event, void* args)
{
  struct callback_args* data = (struct callback_args *)args;
  if (event.getPointIndex () == -1)
    return;
  PointT current_point;
  event.getPoint(current_point.x, current_point.y, current_point.z);
  data->clicked_points_3d->points.push_back(current_point);
  // Draw clicked points in red:
  pcl::visualization::PointCloudColorHandlerCustom<PointT> red (data->clicked_points_3d, 255, 0, 0);
  data->viewerPtr->removePointCloud("clicked_points");
  data->viewerPtr->addPointCloud(data->clicked_points_3d, red, "clicked_points");
  data->viewerPtr->setPointCloudRenderingProperties(pcl::visualization::PCL_VISUALIZER_POINT_SIZE, 10, "clicked_points");
  std::cout << current_point.x << " " << current_point.y << " " << current_point.z << std::endl;
}

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "viewer_node");
  ros::NodeHandle n;
  new_cloud_available_flag = false;

  ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2>("/camera/depth_registered/points", 1000, callback);

  if(pcl::console::find_switch (argc, argv, "--help") || pcl::console::find_switch (argc, argv, "-h"))
        return print_help();

  // Algorithm parameters:
  std::string svm_filename = "/usr/share/doc/libpcl-1.7-doc/doc/pcl-1.7/tutorials/sources/ground_based_rgbd_people_detection/data/trainedLinearSVMForPeopleDetectionWithHOG.yaml";
  float min_confidence = -1.5;
  float min_height = 1.3;
  float max_height = 2.3;
  float voxel_size = 0.06;
  float sampling_factor = 1;
  Eigen::Matrix3f rgb_intrinsics_matrix;
  rgb_intrinsics_matrix << 525, 0.0, 319.5, 0.0, 525, 239.5, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0; // Kinect RGB camera intrinsics

 // Read if some parameters are passed from command line:
  pcl::console::parse_argument (argc, argv, "--svm", svm_filename);
  pcl::console::parse_argument (argc, argv, "--conf", min_confidence);
  pcl::console::parse_argument (argc, argv, "--min_h", min_height);
  pcl::console::parse_argument (argc, argv, "--max_h", max_height);
  pcl::console::parse_argument (argc, argv, "--sample", sampling_factor);

// Wait for the first frame:
  while(!new_cloud_available_flag)
    {
        std::cout<<"waiting for first frame\n";
        ros::Duration(0.001).sleep();
        ros::spinOnce();
    }

std::cout<<"got first frame\n";
new_cloud_available_flag = false;
    
cloud_mutex.lock ();    // for not overwriting the point cloud

// Display pointcloud:
  pcl::visualization::PointCloudColorHandlerRGBField<PointT> rgb(cloud);
  viewer.addPointCloud<PointT> (cloud, rgb, "input_cloud");
  viewer.setCameraPosition(0,0,-2,0,-1,0,0);

  // Add point picking callback to viewer:
  struct callback_args cb_args;
  PointCloudT::Ptr clicked_points_3d (new PointCloudT);
  cb_args.clicked_points_3d = clicked_points_3d;
  cb_args.viewerPtr = pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer::Ptr(&viewer);
  viewer.registerPointPickingCallback (pp_callback, (void*)&cb_args);
  std::cout << "Shift+click on three floor points, then press 'Q'..." << std::endl;

  // Spin until 'Q' is pressed:
  viewer.spin();

  cloud_mutex.unlock ();

  // Ground plane estimation:
  Eigen::VectorXf ground_coeffs;
  ground_coeffs.resize(4);
  std::vector<int> clicked_points_indices;

  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < clicked_points_3d->points.size(); i++)
    {
      clicked_points_indices.push_back(i);
    }

  pcl::SampleConsensusModelPlane<PointT> model_plane(clicked_points_3d);
  model_plane.computeModelCoefficients(clicked_points_indices,ground_coeffs);

  std::cout << "Ground plane: " << ground_coeffs(0) << " " << ground_coeffs(1) << " " << ground_coeffs(2) << " " << ground_coeffs(3) << std::endl;

  // Initialize new viewer:
  pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer viewer("PCL Viewer");          // viewer initialization

  viewer.setCameraPosition(0,0,-2,0,-1,0,0);
  // Create classifier for people detection:  
  pcl::people::PersonClassifier<pcl::RGB> person_classifier;
  person_classifier.loadSVMFromFile(svm_filename);   // load trained SVM

  // People detection app initialization:
  pcl::people::GroundBasedPeopleDetectionApp<PointT> people_detector;    // people detection object
  people_detector.setVoxelSize(voxel_size);                        // set the voxel size
  people_detector.setIntrinsics(rgb_intrinsics_matrix);            // set RGB camera intrinsic parameters
  people_detector.setClassifier(person_classifier);                // set person classifier
  people_detector.setHeightLimits(min_height, max_height);         // set person classifier
  people_detector.setSamplingFactor(sampling_factor);              // set a downsampling factor to the point cloud (for increasing speed)
//  people_detector.setSensorPortraitOrientation(true);              // set sensor orientation to vertical

  // For timing:
  static unsigned count = 0;
  static double last = pcl::getTime ();

  // Main loop:
  while (!viewer.wasStopped() && ros::ok())
  {    
    if (new_cloud_available_flag && cloud_mutex.try_lock ())    // if a new cloud is available
    {        
      new_cloud_available_flag = false; 

      // Perform people detection on the new cloud:
      std::vector<pcl::people::PersonCluster<PointT> > clusters;   // vector containing persons clusters    
      people_detector.setInputCloud(cloud);    
      people_detector.setGround(ground_coeffs);          // set floor coefficients   
      people_detector.compute(clusters);                           // perform people detection    
      ground_coeffs = people_detector.getGround();                 // get updated floor coefficients

      // Draw cloud and people bounding boxes in the viewer:
      viewer.removeAllPointClouds();        
      viewer.removeAllShapes();    

      pcl::visualization::PointCloudColorHandlerRGBField<PointT> rgb(cloud);    
      viewer.addPointCloud<PointT> (cloud, rgb, "input_cloud");

      unsigned int k = 0;

      for(std::vector<pcl::people::PersonCluster<PointT> >::iterator it = clusters.begin(); it != clusters.end(); ++it)
      {    
        if(it->getPersonConfidence() > min_confidence)             // draw only people with confidence above a threshold
        {
          // draw theoretical person bounding box in the PCL viewer:   
          it->drawTBoundingBox(viewer, k);
          k++;   
        }
      }    

      if(k==1)    
        std::cout<<k<<" person found" << std::endl;
      else    
        std::cout << k << " people found" << std::endl;

      viewer1.spinOnce();
      // Display average framerate: 
      if (++count == 30)
      {
        double now = pcl::getTime ();
        std::cout << "Average framerate: " << double(count)/double(now - last) << " Hz" <<  std::endl;
        count = 0;
        last = now;
      }

      cloud_mutex.unlock ();
   }
 }
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/141066/ros-pcl-visualizer-fails-on-turtlebot/) by [kmb11](https://answers.ros.org/users/11806/kmb11/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2014-03-17

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [smithers](https://answers.ros.org/users/20765/smithers/) on 2015-09-15**:
Hello,
I tried to test this code in my computer and I got the following error:

free(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000000742ba0 ***

Did you have any problem similiar to this?

My computer supports  SSE2. Could this be a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've figured it out, it turns out that the Intel Atom on the Turtlebot's computer doesn't support SSE4. The problem is that catkin_make creates cmake files that require SSE4, which is a problem when Eigen classes come in to play and require SSE. I changed all of the cmake files to execute their operations without using SSE4, then built it using `make` in the build folder instead of `catkin_make`.

---

Originally posted by [kmb11](https://answers.ros.org/users/11806/kmb11/) with karma: 81 on 2014-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1